# How to implement Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Tags: jquery, wordpress, server

I am well-versed in HTML and CSS and I know enough JS/Jquery and PHP to get by. But this is all I know, so I don't know where to get started with solving this problem.

My Google Fonts aren't rendering on one of my simple websites (http://ceobusinessalliance.com). I coded it from scratch using Bootstrap and WordPress. They were rendering before but are no longer. According to the error in the console and Google's support page (https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/troubleshooting), I need to make sure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is in the header.

I have no idea what this means and how to get started with searching for an answer. Would someone be kind enough to explain how to implement this code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the functions.php i would try something like that:

```
/** functions.php of your theme */
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_header_acao');
function add_header_acao(){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mark. It didn't seem to work. I put it at the beginning of my functions.php and at the end.

Comment: welcome. Forgot to mention the source where i getting this from:
[link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/wp-function-filter-for-modifying-http-headers)
You need to find an action hook (the template_redirect in my suggestion) where you can change the http header in wordpress